# Building Alert dialog leads to exception when called from TimerTask - Android

Tags: java, android, gps, android-alertdialog

My app originally got GPS coordinates when clicking on one button.

In my activity I am getting my click this way (everything is working fine):

```
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {        
                // create class object
                gps = new GPSTracker(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this);

                // check if GPS enabled     
                if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                    double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                    // \n is for new line
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
                }else{
                    // can't get location
                    // GPS or Network is not enabled
                    // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                    gps.showSettingsAlert();
                }

            }
        });
```

GPSTracker is a **Service** which implements LocationListener and showSettingAlert() build my Alert dialog (if network and gps permissions are not set up) as below

```
public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
// Setting Dialog Title
alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

// Setting Dialog Message
alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

// On pressing Settings button
alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
    }
});

// on pressing cancel button
alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    dialog.cancel();
    }
});

// Showing Alert Message
alertDialog.show();
```

}

Now I need to do it every minute so I included one timerTask but when I try and build my Alert dialog I get a null pointer exception here:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyApp.getContext());
```

MyApp extends Application because I need to have the context everywhere.

- My problem seems to be that when I cannot instantiate **AlertDialog.Builder** from a timerTask, even using a static context. 
  How to solve it?

import android.app.Application;

public class MyApp extends Application {
    private static MyApp mContext;

```
@Override 
public void onCreate() {
    mContext= this;
    super.onCreate();
}

public static MyApp getContext() {
    return mContext;
    }
}
```

For the first part, I was inspired by this [code](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/)

Comment: paste the logcat error here... alteast give the error line where the error is mentioned in logcat

Comment: actually I already mentioned the point where I get the null pointer exception AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyApp.getContext()); I will add MyApp class

Comment: in service you use MyApp.getcontext() ?

Comment: yes, in the class extending Service and implementing LocationListener

Comment: I think you should pass the context to service through intent or constructor and then use that context in this service